Pop_OS! starts in aeroplane mode
I just installed Pop OS. It's great but it always starts in Aeroplane mode. I can just turn off aeroplane mode, but it's annoying. If the laptop goes to sleep, it also wakes in aeroplane mode.
It's an HP Envy laptop I've just been given for work. The laptop does not have a hardware/keyboard button for aeroplane mode. I also found nothing in the bios relating to it. Secure boot is off.

This might be a NetworkManager misconfiguration.  I've seen disabling Wi-Fi in NetworkManager be interpreted as airplain mode in a UI, and NetworkManager has another Enabled/Asleep option for networking overall.  It's possible something is misconfigured and the Wi-Fi option gets flipped with the networking option when it goes to sleep while it doesn't get unflipped, or in the wrong order when waking up.
